# Expand a written c# linq query with string (no methods)

Tags: c#, performance, linq

i have a code like this.

**Context:**

```
public class TestContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
{
    public TestContext()
        : base("name=TestContext")
    {
    }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TestClass> TestClass { get; set; }
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TestSubClass> TestSubClass { get; set; }
}
```

**TestClass:**

```
public class TestClass
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**TestSubClass:**

```
public class TestSubClass
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }

    [Column("Test")]
    public Guid? TestId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TestId")]
    public virtual TestClass Test { get; set; }
}
```

**GetEverything: / Problem**

```
public static IQueryable<TestClass> GetEverything(bool onlyVisible = false)
{
    IQueryable<TestClass> query;

    using(var context = new TestContext())
    {
        query = from test in context.TestClass
                select test;

        if (onlyVisible)
        {
            query
                .Join(context.TestSubClass, test => test.Id, testSub => testSub.TestId, (test, testSub) => new { TestClass = test, TestSubClass = testSub })
                .Where(test => test.TestSubClass.Status == 1)
            ;

            /*
             * I want to add something like this:
             * 
               query += 
                   join testSub in context.TestSubClass on test.Id equals testSub.TestId
                   where testSub.Status == 1
               ;
             */
        }
    }

    return query;
}
```

And if you look at the comment you know what i want.

The problem is that i dont know how to combine multiple of these things performance.

Or how I can combine that better?

I have a basic `query string` which would be extended by additional things.
But i think these additional things are not pretty readable and understable for third persons...

Comment: `TestClass` - Moment, i edit something.

Comment: you can add where conditions to existing `IQueryable` before enumerating it. `IQueryable.Include` is the method for getting related entities in the same query.

Comment: Why i can't use something like this? `query = query.Where(test => test.TestSubClass.Any(t => t.TestId == test.Id && t.Status == 1));` If i add `public virtual ICollection<TestSubClass> TestSubClass { get; set; }` to `TestClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try using the following:

```
public class TestClass
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TestSubClass> TestSubs {get;set;}
}

public class TestSubClass
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }

    [Column("Test")]
    public Guid? TestId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TestId")]
    public virtual TestClass Test { get; set; }
}

public static IQueryable<TestClass> GetEverything(bool onlyVisible = false)
{
      var context = new TestContext();
      var query = from test in context.TestClass
                select test;

      if (onlyVisible)
      {
           query = query.Include(i => i.TestSubs).Where(w => w.TestSubs.Any(a => a.Status == 1));
      }
      return query;
}
```

`Include` instructs EF to eagerly load entities. Check the article on [EF strategies for loading related entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh205756.aspx)

Comment: Thats what i do at the moment :D But how to use the join in the query "string" and the where as extension?

Comment: @PatrickB I've updated my answer, not sure if it will work, though :D

Comment: Thats the same problem :D Maybe is my question not understable? :(

Comment: Can you define the `query string` and what will get in it?

Comment: query string is for me the sql command like `query = from test in ... select test` and functions for me `query = context.TestClass`. Also **query string** is the sql syntax and the functions not.

Comment: Or can you explain that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27401746/expand-a-written-c-sharp-linq-query-with-string-no-methods?noredirect=1#comment43248538_27401746

Comment: So you want a string parsed to LINQ query?

Comment: I want to extend a "string" by a "string". Not a "string" by "LINQ query". But it would be enough if i could use this: `query = query.Where(test => test.TestSubClass.Any(t => t.TestId == test.Id && t.Status == 1));` But i get a error that `Any` not exists for LINQ.

Comment: The syntax is wrong, because you don't have a collection but a plain object. Can you defined 'extend string by string'? What result do you want to get?

Comment: I want to extend `from test in ... select test` by `where test....Status == 1` for example. Or using the Any method the comment above. I have an collection for Entity Framework... Add `public virtual ICollection<TestSubClass> TestSubClass { get; set; }` to `TestClass` :)

Comment: Final question: do you have 1-1 or 1-many relationship between your objects?

Comment: In this example i have a 1-many relationship. Because that I'm using the `.Where(.Any())` construct.

Comment: Thats very cool! But why it doesnt work without the `Include`? Is the `Include` in SQL a left join? Thanks!

Comment: Ah moment! I cant use "Include". I got an error that method not exists. Autcomplete shows only "Intersect".

Comment: You need to add `using System.Data.Entity;`

Comment: I've added an article which explains how Include works

Comment: Thats funny, now the Intersect is missed :D But who cares. Thanks! It works!